# Implementing a custom Navigation Drawer layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to implement a navigation drawer similar to this one [image]

Notice the change when "More tools option is clicked"

[image]

How do i achieve such a custom layout for the navigation Drawer?Hekp will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to know how to create NavigationDrawer in global, or you know how to implement NavigationDrawer, but you need help with specific layout?

Comment: @BozicNebojsa i know how to implement a navigation drawer.only the specific layout is giving me problems.

Comment: This can be done on several ways. I see it as a ExpandableListView where only last item is expandable. Try to look at this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

All you need is here: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

The guidelines and sample code available.

Good luck!